# Mvc 5 supporting legacy ashx links

Tags: c#, redirect, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to support ashx links as in MapRoute?

For example I have this

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ashx",
            url: "test/redirect.ashx",
            defaults: new { controller = "Click", action = "Redirect" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
```

This doesnt work but what im looking for is, if the url starts is www.example.com/test/redirect.ashx?foo=bar it will redirect me to my controller ClickController.Redirect(). is this possible? Am i Doing this wrong?